# Parse Javascript Variables

Tags: javascript, bash, curl, extract

I have a javascript variable that I curl'ed in Bash.

The URL is https://hygoshop.com/collections/best-sellers/products/mystical-moon-lamp

It looks like this:

```
var meta = {"product":{"id":1460229996586,"vendor":"ZINUO Factory Store","type":"","variants":[{"id":12924116893738,"price":2499,"name":"Mystical Moon Lamp - XXS - 7.8 CM\/3.1 INCH","public_title":"XXS - 7.8 CM\/3.1 INCH","sku":""},{"id":12924066201642,"price":2999,"name":"Mystical Moon Lamp - XS - 9 CM\/3.5 INCH","public_title":"XS - 9 CM\/3.5 INCH","sku":""},{"id":12924068036650,"price":4399,"name":"Mystical Moon Lamp - S - 12 CM\/4.7 INCH","public_title":"S - 12 CM\/4.7 INCH","sku":""},{"id":12865176829994,"price":5499,"name":"Mystical Moon Lamp - M - 15 CM\/5.9 INCH","public_title":"M - 15 CM\/5.9 INCH","sku":""},{"id":12924067250218,"price":7499,"name":"Mystical Moon Lamp - L - 18 CM\/7.1 INCH","public_title":"L - 18 CM\/7.1 INCH","sku":""},{"id":12865176862762,"price":8899,"name":"Mystical Moon Lamp - XL - 20 CM\/7.9 INCH","public_title":"XL - 20 CM\/7.9 INCH","sku":""}]},"page":{"pageType":"product","resourceType":"product","resourceId":1460229996586}};
```

How can I extract all these variables (in the meta variable) in bash so that I can write it into a text file and parse it with jq?

Thanks.

Comment: can you please give more details?

Comment: Use `jq` to parse JSON.

Comment: Thanks! The URL is https://hygoshop.com/collections/best-sellers/products/mystical-moon-lamp . I want to extract everything in the "meta" variable.

Comment: "Extract" to what?

Comment: I want to extract the meta variable into a text file and parse it with jq.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -X GET "https://hygoshop.com/collections/best-sellers/products/mystical-moon-lamp" | jq ...
```

Or if you insist on using your `curl` command and want to strip the variable before using `jq`:

```
curl ... | sed 's/^[^{]*//;s/;$//' | jq ...
```

Comment: Works GOOD. THANKS!!